# C++ file reading and split columns

Tags: c++, tabs, newline, strip, file-read

I'm not familiar with C++ file reading, but I've done a lot via pyspark. 
So right now I have a txt file that reads as follows:

```
1   52  Hayden Smith        18:16   15  M   Berlin

2   54  Mark Puleo      18:25   15  M   Berlin

3   97  Peter Warrington    18:26   29  M   New haven

4   305 Matt Kasprzak       18:53   33  M   Falls Church

5   272 Kevin Solar     19:17   16  M   Sterling

6   394 Daniel Sullivan     19:35   26  M   Sterling

7   42  Kevan DuPont        19:58   18  M   Boylston

8   306 Chris Goethert      20:00   43  M   Falls Church
```

As you can see there are 8 columns and 351 rows(which I've only shown 8 rows),
for each row, [0] is ranking, [1] is BIB, [2] is firstname, [3] is lastname, [4] is time, [5] is age, [6] is sex, [7] is town
for example, the first row, 1 is ranking, 52 is BIB, Hayden Smith is name, 18:16 is time, 15 is age, M is male, Berlin is town.

I have a sorted linked structure, called: Class SortedLinked
and an itemtype class, called: Class Runner

you don't need to worry about the SortedLinked class.

Class Runner has four private attributes:

```
string name, int age, int min, int sec
```

In my driver file, I can do this:

```
SortedLinked mylist                  // initialize a sorted list

Runner M("Jordan", 22, 20, 20)       // initialize a Runner called Jordan, who is 22 years old, and finished the race in 20 mins and 20 sec

mylist.add(M) //add Runner M into my sorted list
```

So I need to read the text file and and create a Runner object with the runner's name, age, number of minutes, and number of seconds. Insert that Runner into a sorted linked list.

So if this is in pyspark, I can just do this:

```
file=sc.textFile("hdfs")             //we usually use hdfs in pyspark

newfile = file.map(lambda line: line.split('\t')    //for each column, they are seperated by Tabs, except column[2][3] are separated by a space 

ColumnIneed = newfile.filter(lambda r: [r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5]]) // I only need the column [2][3][4][5]

mylist = ColumnIneed.collect()    // transform the RDD into a list

Then I can just transform every row into a Runner object.
```

BUT, in C++ I only know this:

```
ifstream, infile;

string s, sAll;

if(infile.is_open())
{

   while(getline(line, s))

   {

      s = s.rstrip('\n')     //does NOT work in C++
      name, age, time = s.split('\t')  // Does NOT work in C++ and I dont need all the columns
```

SO, problem:

1, I need to access each line, and strip the newline

2, I only need the column [2][3][4][5] // each column is separated by Tabs

3, column[4] is time, which is string in the textfile, I need to split ":" and put into mintues and seconds

4, column[2][3] are first and last names, I need to combine them into string name

5, column[2][3] are separated by spaces

so ideally, I want to do this:

```
while(I need a loop)
{

   eachline = access each line;

   eachline.strip('\n')  //strip newline

   eachline.split('\t')  //split Tabs

   string name = eachline[2][3];

   string time = eachline[4];

   int min;

   int sec;

   min, sec = time.split(':")

   int age = eachline[5];

   Runner M(name, age, min, sec)    //I don't know if this works, because it looks like you are overwriting the Runner M each time you access a new line. 

   mylist.add(M)      //add M into my linkedlist, this step you don't need to worry, I already finished. 

}
```

if you have a better way of doing, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please edit your formatting.

Comment: A similar question was asked earlier today. It may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786613/populating-a-string-vector-with-tab-delimited-text

Answer (score 2):

Some code snippet

```
    std::ifstream in;
    in.open(/*path to file*/);
    std::string line;
    if(in.is_open())
    {
        while(std::getline(in, line)) //get 1 row as a string
        {
            std::istringstream iss(line); //put line into stringstream
            std::string word;
            while(iss >> word) //read word by word
            {
                std::cout << word << std::endl;
            }
            /*
            int row;
            int age;
            std::string name;
            iss >> row >> age >> name; // adopt to your input line
            Runner M(name, age, min, sec); //common agreement - variables shouldn't start with capital, you don't override M, each time u create new local variable type of Runner, then you put copy of M into some container, M gets destroyed at the end of the block, probably you could use movement semantic, but you need C++ basics first    
            mylist.add(M);
            */
        }
    }
```

Comment: let me give it a try

Comment: Recommend tweaking that code to actually handle tabs. Right now it will split on all whitespace, not just tabs.

Comment: std::istringstream iss(line)    // incomplete type is not allowed, what is happening.  never mind, forgot to include <sstream>

Comment: You could use `while(getline(iss, word, '\t'))` to get tab seperated words. So the e.g. name will be one word instead of two.